# dialog for editing QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

I have a stand-alone pyqgis app, some layers are using the QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2 as renderer with customized range and color symbol. I am trying to use an existing Qgs Dialog control to allow users to edit the breakdown and symbol etc of those layers. Out of all of the qgs controls, I found the following as the most probable:

```
cr = QgsVectorGradientColorRampV2()
ed = QgsVectorGradientColorRampV2Dialog(cr, None)
ed.exec_()
```

But, I don't think it does what I want as it only allows percent category, not real double values ranges.

So, which editor should I use for QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2 type of style? or do I have to make my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QGis control to use is `QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2Widget`, one just have to put it inside a custom control like a dialog